# How to xUnit test against AccountController's actual ASP.NET Core 1.0 Identity tables without mocking?

Tags: entity-framework, tdd, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-1.0, xunit.net

There are more than a few articles about unit testing against the ASP.NET Core 1.0 AccountController.

It seems that none of them actually involve testing the contents of the real Asp.Net Core 1.0 Identity tables.

There are 7 tables:

```
AspNetUsers
AspNetUserTokens
AspNetUserLogins
AspNetUserRoles
AspNetUserClaims
AspNetRoles
AspNetRoleClaims
```

in a .NET Core Web API application, the flow (except for external code framework parts we do not see) is first through Main

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

From `var host = ...` we enter `public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)` in Startup.cs; after that the runtime method `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` allows configuration:

```
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();
```

*et cetera*

Finally `host.Run();` puts our .NET Core Web API application into a listening mode.

`http://localhost:58796/account/login` causes a **Log in** form to be returned.

The constructor for the AccountController looks like this:

```
    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ISmsSender smsSender,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _smsSender = smsSender;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
    }
```

This means that a **UserManager** and a **SignInManager** must be passed in to the `AccountController`; the SignInManager can not be null and requires a non-null UserManager and a non-null logger:

```
   public SignInManager(UserManager<TUser> userManager,
       IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
       IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory,
       IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
       ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>> logger);
```

Setting up the **logger** is relatively simple in our xUnit.net method:

```
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                                      .AddConsole()
                                      .AddDebug();
```

Setting up the **userManager** is more complicated in our xUnit.net method:

```
    public UserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher,
            IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators, 
            IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, 
            ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
            IServiceProvider services,
            ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger);
```

Part of the challenge is the complexity of implementing the `interface IUserStore<TUser>` *contract* for the **store**:

```
// Summary:  Provides an abstraction for a store which manages user accounts.
//   TUser:  The type encapsulating a user.
public interface IUserStore<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : class
{
    Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<string> GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(TUser user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task SetUserNameAsync(TUser user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

For the normal use of the `AccountController` much of the complexity is buried behind the scenes by the ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API wiring which takes care of providing access to the Identity database tables via EF Core 1.0.

For unit testing with xUnit.net without mocking (because we want to access the "real database"), *the problem* is that the flow is like this:

```
 [Fact]
 // Arrange
     ...
 // Act
     ... // the AccountController is not available yet
 var accountController
     = new AccountController(userManager: ...,
              signInManager: ...,
                emailSender: null,
                smsSender: null,
                loggerFactory: loggerFactory); // can NOT be null
.............
```

in a nutshell, ***the problem*** is a **catch 22** ~~ Start.cs sets up everything we need, however, our xUnit.net test is running before Start.cs has been run.

a .zip can be found here [github.com/gerryLowry/RawCoreAPIxUnit](https://github.com/gerryLowry/RawCoreAPIxUnit)

a not zipped version can be found here
[github.com/gerryLowry/EF_Core_testing_experiments](https://github.com/gerryLowry/EF_Core_testing_experiments)

Comment: the "work in progress" xUnit.net test [Fact] GerryLowryAtSomewhereComCanLogIn() only *appears* to pass because it is an incomplete test.

Comment: why do you want to test this in a unit test? Your not testing your own code. Sound like you want to create a integration test using your application/code. So pick a framework fit for it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe give `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` (ships with Asp.Net Core for integration testing) a go.

You can initialize the `TestServer` in the constructor of your test class and wire up your custom `Startup.cs` with it. Then register mock implementations of all of `AccountController`'s dependencies except for your one real database dependency.

For the "real database" construct `UserManager` with `UserStore` and Entity Framework implementation of `IUserStore` [(link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613259(v=vs.108).aspx)